# What is difference between projection plane and projective plane $P^2?$

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, projection, homogeneous-spaces

**Projection plane:**
The general processing steps for modeling and converting a world coordinate description of a scene to
device coordinates, we need projection plane.

**Projective plane:** We know that $P^2$ is all $\mathbb R^2$ points and point at infinity.In projection plane any point exists in $(∞,∞)$ if we want to represents it then we need projective plane.

For instance, a point in Cartesian $(1, 2)$ becomes $(1, 2, 1)$ in Homogeneous. If a point, $(1, 2)$, moves toward infinity, it becomes $(∞,∞)$ in Cartesian coordinates. And it becomes $(1, 2, 0)$ in Homogeneous coordinates, because of $(1/0, 2/0) ≈ (∞,∞).$ Notice that we can express the point at infinity without using $"∞".$

My question is what's difference between Projection plane and Projective plane?

Comment: Can you recall the definition of the projection plane?

Comment: @Arctic there are many steps to represent a objects in projection plane.

Comment: There is more than one point at infinity in the projective plane. There really isn’t much relation between the two concepts, they just have similar names. There is a loose association, perhaps, but not one which will elucidate either concept much.

Comment: @Thomas we mean they are totally different things?

Comment: “Totally different” is a loaded term. They are both geometric objects. They might have similar historic roots and motivations (not sure.) But a projection plane is an “affine” plane, while projective planes are not. A projection plane is specifically a subspace of a higher-dimensional space, but a projective plane is not necessarily.

Comment: @Thomas could explain in one line what is affine” plane?

Comment: I suppose you could have examples of projection planes in projective geometry, high thus would be projection planes. But studying these would have no  relevance  on graphics rendering tha I can see.

Comment: @Thomas I m computer science student. I don't understand projective geometry. I know projective plane and projection plane. But can't differentiate between these. Could answer easily by which I can understand.

Comment: As a computer scientist, you don’t need to understand projective planes. It has no computational bearing on the computation of images from $3$-dimensional space onto a screen.

Comment: @Thomas one thing tell whenever I capture any image by camera like where two parallel lines seems to be intersect like "railway track image" then this points at infinity will appear in camera display which is called projective plane?

Comment: That's certainly a decent way to look at horizons, but that is not about projective planes, but projective 3-space.

Comment: @Thomas But projective plane subset of projective 3-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's difference between Projection plane and Projective plane?

I would say that "projection plane" describes its role. Namely, it implies that you are projecting from some higher-dimensional space (e.g. 3d) to that plane.

Conversely "projective plane" describes its structure. What kinds of points it contains, what axioms it satisfies. The fact that using homogeneous coordinates makes sense.

Your can do a projection from a 3d space onto a projection plane that also happens to be a projective plane. Doing so will allow you to preserve direction information for things "at infinity". You can even consider the map between 3d homogeneous coordinate vectors and their planar interpretation to be such a projection from a 3d space to the projective plane at $z=1$ using the origin as center of projection.

But the two concepts don't need to go together. You can do projection onto a plane while staying purely with an affine description of that plane. You can talk about the properties of the projective plane without any projection involved in the process. So from that perspective I'd consider the two concepts to be fairly independent.

Comment: "affine description of that plane " means without using homogeneous corordinates?

Comment: @User4567: If you operate in coordinates, then yes. On a more coordinate-free level, it means that if you have a point on a plane that is parallel to the projection plane, and passing through the center of projection, then the image of that point under projection would in an affine setup be undefined, while under projective setup it would be a point at infinity.

Comment: "3d homogeneous coordinate vectors" means (x, y, 1) or (x, y, z, 1) ? Because different website says different that's why I am asking..

Comment: I meant $(x,y,1)$.

Comment: your statement "Doing so will allow you to preserve direction information for things "at infinity".""---- what you mean by "preserve direction information ", you mean $(x, y, 0)$ ?